# PHP check if 0x0 is always true

Tags: php, if-statement

I am reading some binary dataset and wanted to check if some value is x'00'. But my condition always returned true and I have no idea why...

My try was to do like that:

```
$value = 'i am not x0';
if ($value == 0x0) {
    echo "it is true" . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo "it is false" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Why this if results in true?

Comment: in short: type coercion. use `===`

Comment: The third answer to the duplicate is the most applicable to your situation, but all are worth reading.

Comment: Thx a lot, did not find this question when I searched. But now it is clear to me.